# Can code stored in a table be used to dynamically fill an unbound textbox in an Access report

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have an access table that I want to use to make a dynamic template for building a report. How do I use the values stored in that table in the report? As the programmer, I know how to manually write the code in the report...BUT...I want to store the information in a table instead of hard coding it, to give the USER the ability to modify the template of the report, long after I've gone.

Specifically:

- Enter this in table: **1. The person of interest is [First] [Last]**
- I will use code to modify the user entered value as: **"1. The person of interest is " & [First] & " " & [Last]**
- In the Report, I want the unbound textbox to pull the information stored in the table to change the ControlSource so that when the report runs you get the desired outcome: **1. The person of interest is John Doe**

I have tried using MyText.ControlSource = [TemplateField], but all this does is makes the report show the contents of the text field. I'm guessing I need to escape the code in some way so that the report reads the items in "[  ]" as code vice text, but I can't figure out how to do that while storing it at the same time.

Comment: Textbox does not have RecordSource, it has ControlSource. When setting ControlSource, static text part needs to be enclosed in quote marks. The example you show is missing the opening quote mark. However, setting to a field that holds static text and field names will just be seen as a single string, which is what you are experiencing. I don't know any way to accomplish what you want - no way to 'escape' and evaluate as field name references. Just need to build report with necessary static content (labels) and textboxes bound to fields.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.. I fixed for any future readers.

Comment: What event did you even use to set textbox ControlSource? I think what you wanted would be even more complicated for users. Would they have to know to include [ ] characters appropriately in typed input?

Comment: My example above is way simplified.. I used a form that allows the user to type free text, and then from a combo box they choose the field to enter. Each time the combo changes (afterupdate) I run vb to fill the textbox. It actually works beautifully.. up until I can't use the data for anything.

Comment: I figured a way I *could* do it.. it works, but it's not as clean as I'd like it to be. The user "builds" the template using the form I already created- and then when all the textboxes are filled (there are many dynamic portions of this report)- I can use vb to cycle through the textbox and break out each text field (by searching for the [ ]) and then change the controlsource of the textfield in the saved report. Then.. when I call the report (from another form) it would just be filling in the data like a normal report.

Comment: Yes, parsing field content and rebuilding to set ControlSource might work - although not the 'escaping' you were looking for. Are you programmatically opening report in design view, setting textbox ControlSource then saving report?